# Is there a way to insert text into dataframe name in a function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm using a function to aggregate a large amount of data and I was wondering if there's a way to insert text into a dataframe name as part of a function?

For example in SAS I would use an '@' symbol which could be used to insert text into the function.

```
def function (year):
       df@year = '@year'
       return df@year
```

Of course this doesn't output to a dataframe so in this case the variable name, but so that when I use the function I don't have to use for example `function(df2007, '2007')`

Comment: Can you be more elaborate?

Comment: What are you referring to when you mention "the dataframe name"?

Comment: @Seon of course this doesn't output to a dataframe so in this case the variable name, but so that when I use the function I don't have to use for example ```function(df2007, '2007')```

Comment: Still not 100% sure I understood what you want to do, but you might want to take a look at the `str` function - `str(2017) -> '2017'`.

Comment: keep it in dictionary - `all_dfs["df@2007"]= df` - and then you use string as key to access it so you can easyly change this string/key. it is better and much simpler then creating separted variables like `df2007`, `df2008`. etc